# Swift: how to adjust custom high res image size to button? its too big(screenshots attached)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

in Xcode interface builder, i used the highest resolution from https://github.com/hampusborgos/country-flags , 1000 pixels but the image is too big when i assign it to the button. I want to create a game for all country flags and tried figuring out a couple hours how to fit image within the button but to no avail.

Anyone can help how xcode, interface builder, can auto-resize to fit within the button size? attached 3 screenshots below

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WvMzrkVw172Tou25m9nILbqffAZfSu6L/view?usp=sharing

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vfaLfI8nKl4Bmk_1MMWYXX5fWpheMiZe/view?usp=sharing

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1m2Zq0xRoGPvO59ZXlDHvTya1cHcs0iji/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

```
flagButton.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
```

just change the content mode of the button's imageView
just write this code in viewWillAppear or viewDidLoad

Comment: does not work. possible to use interface builder to fit image within button?https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZrvFoYM18AbZGeRLY_42sshXXBtUAUgo/view?usp=sharing

Comment: button.clipstobound = true ?

Comment: the image gets cropped off

Comment: https://github.com/hampusborgos/country-flags im trying to use the 1000 pixel flags . i tried putting the 1000 pixel flag in side a button that is 200 by 100 but the image is too big.

Comment: for buttons, i think the image does not automatically resize to button size, unlike for imageview.

Comment: no button have imageview in it and you can easily fit the image by using contentmode

Comment: ok thanks, i resized the images to smaller size to fit inside the buttons. will try contentmode next time.